# AlertDialog not showing up

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, apk

I am trying to make a simple little test on an Android emulator called YouWave for Android 4.1.1 (I believe it is).

I am using IntelliJ to generate an APK file to use with the emulator. I simply went into Artifacts and made one Artifact to create an APK file. Didn't do anything else.

[image: Project Structure Menu]

The idea of the app is simple. When some code have run, show the results of the code in a little box that I can read and then close when I have read it. But when I fire the application in the emulator it says "Loading 100 %" and then nothing happens. (It worked with two other applications that came with the software so I know it works otherwise.)

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.DalvikTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        long time = RunTest();
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Results");
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        String s = "Time: " + time + " ns";
        builder
                .setMessage(s)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        MyActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    public long RunTest() {
        long timeStart = System.nanoTime();
        long sum = 0;
        int[] arr = new int[1000000];
        for(int i : arr) {
            sum += i;
        }
        long timeEnd = System.nanoTime();
        long result = timeEnd - timeStart;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Why is the box with the results now showing up?

Comment: Try moving your `runTest()` and AlertDialog to the onResume instead of onCreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry, i cant comment because i have not enough reputation,

what i want to say is:

i tested youre code and it worked so it should be fine.

and to clean up youre code type this in oncreate:

```
showDialog();
```

and under oncreate type youre code like this:

```
public void showDialog() {
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Results");
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        String s = "Time: " + time + " ns";
        builder
                .setMessage(s)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        MyActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

Comment: I just used it in the normal emulator instead of YouWave, and it works. You get an accepted for cleaning up the code a bit :)

Answer (score 2):

I used YouWave some time ago and had the problem of some apps not working too.
Your problem might be in the fact that you are using debugable and development signed apk file that YouWave player doesn't support (It didn't work in older versions at least) and you need to export your file signed with production key. It's quite simple actually because you can generate your own key, considering your rep on website I am guessing you are already familiar with this proces put for reference if someone needs to know everything is explained here http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: I thought it wasn't necessary since emulators don't really need signed applications. But I will give it a try!

Comment: It's something to do with YouWave. The signing thing is probably the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. NOTE: Although it's possible to create unsigned apks they are useful only when you want someone to sign it later in all other cases you shouldn't use them.